# 253006: File doesn't exist: ['/Users/oscar/Desktop/data.txt']

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

Receiving intermittent snowflake python connector error while trying to load file onto table.

Gives error in following code:

exe.execute("""PUT 'file:///Users/oscar/Desktop/data.txt'

'@"db"."schema".%"table"/ui4654116544'""")

Comment: if anything rewriting the file? is the file open in an editor, that might have a lock on the file?

Comment: No. The file is newly created each time the code is ran. I use the exact same approach in other programs, not sure why it sometimes sends an error for this case.

Comment: by newly, again, within sub second? because if you write the file in one process, and try read it by another system process, the operating system may not have flushed the file yet.

Comment: The file name is distinct to this process alone and then deleted at the very end. Also, the error only happens at a random moments throughout the day with no real pattern as to why it occurs. Appreciate the help and the questions by the way!

Comment: I have also tried renaming the file, changing its path and altered the code to retry upon an exception. Sometimes retrying works but mostly not, even with a lag upon the next retry.

Comment: hmm, so if/with "retry" you are meaning order of seconds? if so, then it's not a local file system/os thing.

Comment: Right, and it's only for this process. I run the same method for other process and it's only this one in particular.

Comment: Can you try **if os.path.exists(file_name): print("File exists")** as we use **os.path.exists** to check if the file is actually present at that path.

Comment: That actually helped me find the problem. When it scraped for the data and there was none at that particular moment it wrote nothing to the file so I guess it would just not create it. Thanks friends!